# android tabHost with many activities inside each tab

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

I have an android app that should go to a different activity when a tab is tapped,

but once in that tab, the user should be able to go to different activities [views] inside that tab,

I have found this [multiple activities in tab](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

But I wonder if this is the best and simplest approach, to have a TabGroupActivity that extends ActivityGroup,

or is there other preferred way to have multiple activities in my tabs?

edit,
is it a better approach to use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) as aneal suggest?

thanks!

ps.
I want to use this app for mobile phones, with a minimum OS v 2.1

So do fragments work with old OS? and in a handset phone?

;)

Comment: You should use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

Comment: hi @aneal, thanks, do you have an example of the tabHost with fragments to accomplish my goal?, thanks again ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple Activities you found using [this](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html), is using ActivityGroup which is now deprecated, and suggested to use Fragments in place of it.

To support android devices 2.1+ and higher in you case, you can surely use Android support packages which are available for download. And compatible fragment work for Android device with v1.6 and higher, if you wish to work with fragments.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by aneal use fragments. You find [some examples in the SDK](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/index.html#Fragment). [Here](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/) is an article that goes through the same thing as shown in the "Fragment tabs" SDK example.